# Understdanding the definition of the perimeter of a set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, bounded-variation

The total variation of a function $u\in L^1_{loc} (\Omega)$ is defined as 
$$\text{TV}(u,\Omega)= \sup \, \bigg\{ -\int_{\Omega} u\, div \phi \, dx : 
 \phi \in C_c^{\infty} (\Omega,\mathbb{R}^N), \, \lvert \phi (x) \rvert \leq 1\, \forall x\in \Omega
 \bigg \}.  $$

Now if $E \subseteq \Omega$, the *perimeter* of $E$ is defined as the total variation of its characteristic function $\chi_E$:
$$ \text{Per}(E)= \text{TV}(\chi_E,\Omega)= \sup \, \bigg\{ -\int_{E}\, div \phi \, dx : 
 \phi \in C_c^{\infty} (\Omega,\mathbb{R}^N), \, \lvert \phi (x) \rvert \leq 1\, \forall x\in \Omega
 \bigg \}.$$ 
My question is, how do you practically calculate the perimeter of a given set, using this formula? 
For example, for a tyical square $\square$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with each of its sides having length 1,  we'd expect the Per to equal 4 but I get this:
$$ \text{Per}(\square)= \text{TV}(\chi_{\square},\Omega)= \sup \, \bigg\{ -\int_{\square}\, div \phi \, dx : 
 \phi \in C_c^{\infty} (\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2), \, \lvert \phi (x) \rvert \leq 1\, \forall x\in \Omega
 \bigg \} = \int 1 \ dx dy = 1 $$ 
which is more like the *area* of the square, not its perimeter. Or am I wrong?

Thanks bunches.

Answer (score 0):

For the square $[0, 1] \times [0,1]$ you can't actually *achieve* the supremum, because the boundary (or more precisely the outward normal along the boundary) does not vary smoothly. But consider a $\phi$ that is $(1, 0)$ on $\{1\} \times [\epsilon, 1 - \epsilon]$, $(0,1)$ on $[\epsilon, 1-\epsilon] \times \{1\}$ etc. Then its integral along the boundary will be approximately $4(1 - 2\epsilon) \to 4$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. The integral $\int_E \operatorname{div} \phi$ will also be approximately $4(1 - 2\epsilon)$, in fact the exact same value, but this is harder to see directly and depends on exactly how you construct such a $\phi$.

The reason you're getting $1$ is because you replaced $\operatorname{div} \phi$ in the integral by $1$, which is not valid, even if $\lVert \phi \rVert = 1$ on the boundary.

For an example of an explicit calculation that doesn't really satisfy all the constraints, consider $\phi(x, y) = (x, y)$ and $E$ to be the unit circle, $\{(x, y) \mid x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$. Then $\operatorname \phi = 2$ identically, so $\int_E \operatorname{div} \phi = \int_E 2 = 2\pi$, which is the perimeter of $E$.

Note that the $\phi$ in this example does not have compact support and does not satisfy $|\phi| \le 1$ outside $E$. Both of these issues could be fixed using bump functions, but that would make the computation above much harder/impossible.

Comment: Just noticed the extra sign in the question but that does not really affect the argument, you could replace $\phi$ by $-\phi$ everywhere.